# Reading Dictionary in Array with Django to HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I have the following dictionary:

```
export = {
        'target': target_name,
        'chats': [
            {
                'name': 'name',
                'time': 'time',
            }, {
                'name': 'name',
                'time': 'time',
            },
        ],
    }
```

What I want to do is to pass these values to a dynamically generated HTML file.

```
{{ for chat in chats }}
        <h3>{{ chat.name }}</h3>
{{ endfor }}
```

If I try to do this it returns the following error: `Could not parse the remainder: ' chat in chats' from 'for chat in chats'`

I am already returning the dictionary, so I can do `<h3>{{ target }}</h3>`

Comment: it is `{% for ... %} ... {% endfor %}`. So with `{% ... %}` instead of `{{ ... }}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is right and also {% for chat in chats.items %}